# referencing DOM elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

I would select multiple DOM elements using a typical code such as this:

```
$('#ele1, #ele2, #ele3').click(function () {});
```

If I have variables of each DOM element, e.g.

```
var domEle1 = $('#ele1');
var domEle2 = $('#ele2');
var domEle3 = $('#ele3');
```

How can I select them all at once? Instead of individually...

```
domEle1.click(function () {});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jQuery(
    [domEle1, domEle2, domEle3]
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

It's like that:

```
$(domEle1).add(domEle2).add(domEle3).hide(); //for example
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array for this:

```
$( [ '#ele1', '#ele2', '#ele3' ] ).click( function() {
   //...
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$([domEle1, domEle2, domEle3]).each( function() {
    $(this).click(function(){alert('hello')});
})
```